# NSButton: show alternate image on hover

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

I've a `NSButton` with both an *Image* and *Alternate Image*. I would like the alternate image to be shown on hover. To solve this, I've extended the *NSButton* to show the alternate image when hovering the view. Is there a better solution to this?

My solution:

```
@interface HoverButton()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTrackingArea *trackingArea;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSImage *imageTmp;
@end

@implementation HoverButton

-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseEntered:theEvent];

    [self updateImages];
    self.image = self.alternateImage;
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super mouseExited:theEvent];

    self.image = self.imageTmp;
}

- (void)updateImages {
    self.imageTmp = self.image;
}

-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(self.trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:self.trackingArea];
    }

    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    self.trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                     options:opts
                                                       owner:self
                                                    userInfo:nil];

    [self addTrackingArea:self.trackingArea];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is better suited to an `NSButtonCell` subclass. you can do it in one method and it won't apply to all NSButtons (I doubt thats what you actually want). Just set your button cell type in IB to your custom subclass.

here is some code I just wrote and tested that works:

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    if (_alternateImageOrKeyEquivalentFont && _bcFlags2.mouseInside) {
        // the draw bezel call is optional. maybe you don't want it
        [self drawBezelWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
        [self drawImage:_alternateImageOrKeyEquivalentFont
              withFrame:cellFrame
                 inView:controlView];
    } else {
        [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame
                              inView:controlView];
    }
}
```

you will need to set the `showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside` to `YES` probably in an `init` method for the cell.

Comment: While this works, it will be rejected via the app store as `_alternateImageOrKeyEquivalentFont` and `_bcFlags2` are private api.

Comment: @Zenox what makes them private exactly? they are declared right in the header file for the world to see. I don't know what the exact rules are since I dont publish on the App store; enlighten me please.

Comment: This has a great answer to what is private: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580251/what-exactly-is-a-private-api-and-why-will-apple-reject-an-ios-app-if-one-is-us. As to this specific instance: http://imgur.com/2PFuEqM.

Comment: @Zenox thank you, that certainly answers it :) I'll try to remember to update this answer with a suitable non-private solution when I have time.

Comment: For mouseInside, you just have to implement `-mouseEntered:` and `-mouseExited:` in your `NSButtonCell` subclass and set a local `mouseInside` property.

Answer (score 0):

*CustomButton.h*

```
@interface CustomButton : NSButton
@property (getter=isMouseInside) BOOL mouseInside;
@end
```

*CustomButton.m*

```
@implementation CustomButton

+ (Class)cellClass
{
    return [CustomButtonCell class];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonCustomButtonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonCustomButtonInit
{
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = nil;
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect
                                                  owner:self
                                               userInfo:nil];

    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{
    self.mouseInside = YES;
    if ([self.cell isKindOfClass:[CustomButtonCell class]])
    {
        CustomButtonCell *cell = self.cell;
        cell.mouseInside = YES;
    }
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
    self.mouseInside = NO;
    if ([self.cell isKindOfClass:[CustomButtonCell class]])
    {
        CustomButtonCell *cell = self.cell;
        cell.mouseInside = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

*CustomButtonCell.h*

```
@interface CustomButtonCell : NSButtonCell
@property (getter=isMouseInside) BOOL mouseInside;
@end
```

*CustomButtonCell.m*

```
@implementation CustomButtonCell
@end
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889629/23028).