# How to modify look and feel of NSButton to create toggle effect

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

How to modify look and feel of NSButton, I want to create a toggle button which looks similar to NSRoundRectBezelStyle but with Image and custom height

How do i change background color, color change on hover, change color on click, create toggle effect when state is ON or OFF, create border which is similar to NSRoundRectBezelStyle. Existing native button doesn't have exact UI as that of my UI Element.

UI should look something like below, but I want to add Image above text also.

[image]

**This Mac** Button - **Hover** effect

**Desktop** Button - **Toggle ON** effect

**Shared** Button - **Toggle OFF** effect

Comment: If the native `NSButton` can't do what you want, you have to create a subclass of `NSButton` and/or `NSButtonCell`. Read [Button Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Button.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000019-BAJFBADA). Is an icon checkbox what you want?

Comment: Yes, but documentation doesn't have enough explanation of implementation. Kindly provide some link which have some detailed information on implementation. And i don't want check box, i want toggle button, push on push off type of button.

Comment: From [Using Checkboxes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/CheckBoxes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000251-BCIBFHAA): "**Icon Checkboxes** You can also have a checkbox that’s an icon button; that is, one that’s primarily identified by its icon and has little or no text. If the button’s off, it appears to be sticking out. If the button’s on, it appears to be pressed in. (An icon button cannot display the mixed state.)

Comment: You can create an icon checkbox in either Interface Builder or programmatically. If you use Interface Builder, start with a push button. If you create it programmatically, create an instance of NSButton. Then change it by setting its type to NSPushOnPushOffButton, its image position to NSImageOnly, its bezel type to a square bezel type. Then set the image to what you want.". Give it a try.

Comment: Hover: [NSButton: show alternate image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859782/nsbutton-show-alternate-image-on-hover). Instead of the alternate image, draw an alternate background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a NSButton with the following attributes:

Style: "Push"; Type: "Push On Push Off"; Bordered: "Yes"

And subclassing NSButton and overriding few of its methods.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if(self)
    {
        self.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setState:(NSControlStateValue)state
{
    if(state == NSControlStateValueOn)
    {
        self.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = YES;
    }
}
```

This will yield a result as such:

Toggle OFF effect

[image]

Hover effect

[image]

Toggle ON effect

[image]

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just this:

```
let button = NSButton(title: "Title", target: self, action: #selector(doSomething(_:)))
button.setButtonType(.pushOnPushOff)
button.bezelStyle = NSButton.BezelStyle.recessed
// the magic line
button.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
```

Comment: because of button.bezelStyle = NSButton.BezelStyle.recessed, height is fixed.